# Filtering a list with jQuery, when multiple words are entered as input, using AND condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I'm trying to filter a list based on user input, with jQuery. So far it works OK, but I'd like to be able to filter the list adequately if the user inputs more than one word, using the equivalent of an AND condition.

For example, if the user enters "Toyota manual", the following two elements shoud still be displayed:

1. Toyota Echo 2001 manual
2. Toyota Corolla 2006 manual

At the moment, with the current jsFiddle, the filter looks for the exact string ("Toyota manual") so it doesn't find one. How can I modify my code to make it work as intended?

**HTML/JS**

```
    <label for="filterCars">Filtrer la liste des indicateurs :</label>
<input id="filterCars" class="txtfilterCars" type="text" name="txtRecherche">
<ul class="filterCars">
    <li class="elemCar">Ford escort 2001 manual</li>
    <li class="elemCar">Ford escort 2002 automatic</li>
    <li class="elemCar">Dodge Caravan 2001 automatic</li>
    <li class="elemCar">Hyundai Excel 2003 manual</li>
    <li class="elemCar">Toyota Echo 2001 manual</li>
    <li class="elemCar">Toyota Corolla 2006 manual</li>
    <li class="elemCar">Hyundai Accent 2009 Automatic</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function () {

    function noaccent(myString) {
        temp = myString.replace(/[àâä]/g, "a");
        temp = temp.replace(/[éèêë]/g, "e");
        temp = temp.replace(/[îï]/g, "i");
        temp = temp.replace(/[ôö]/g, "o");
        temp = temp.replace(/[ùûü]/g, "u");
        temp = myString.replace(/[ÀÂÄ]/g, "A");
        temp = temp.replace(/[ÉÈÊË]/g, "E");
        temp = temp.replace(/[ÎÏ]/g, "I");
        temp = temp.replace(/[ÔÖ]/g, "O");
        temp = temp.replace(/[ÙÛÜ]/g, "U");

        return temp;
    }

    $("#filterCars").keyup(

    function () {
        var filter = noaccent($(this).val()),
            count = 0;
        $(".filterCars li.elemCar").each(

        function () {
            if (noaccent($(this).text()).search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).addClass("cacheElementFiltre");
            } else if (!($(this).hasClass("cacheElement"))) {
                $(this).removeClass("cacheElementFiltre");
                count++;
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
//CSS
    .cacheElement, .cacheElementFiltre {
        display: none;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f52o3kpd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you would need to use more advanced regular expression:

```
$("#filterCars").keyup(function () {

    var text = $.trim(noaccent($(this).val())),
        filter = '^(?=.*\\b' + text.split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(filter, 'i'),
        count = 0;

    $(".filterCars li.elemCar").each(function () {

        if (!reg.test(noaccent($(this).text()))) {
            $(this).addClass("cacheElementFiltre");
        } else if (!($(this).hasClass("cacheElement"))) {
            $(this).removeClass("cacheElementFiltre");
            count++;
        }
    });
});
```

Regexp looks complex but it will allow filtering by words in arbitrary order: "Ford 2001" or "2001 Ford".

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/f52o3kpd/2/